# Validation when Creating an Account JAVA

Tags: java, validation

So there is this certain part of my program where I can create an account and the created account will be inserted into my database. And I'm trying to code something where *refer to the code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String user = userField.getText().trim();
    String pass = passField.getText().trim();
    String conPass = confirmPass.getText().trim();  
try{    

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(e.getSource()==submit){

            if (user.equals(user)&&pass.length()==0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fill in the empty field!");
            }//check if the pass field is blank
            else if(user.length()<5){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Username must be at least 5 characters!");
            }
            else if(user.equals(user)&&pass.equals(conPass)&&pass.length()!=0){
                String sqlLogin = "insert into tblLogin (username,pssword) values ('"+user+"','"+pass+"')";;
                getQuery(sqlLogin); 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account Successfully Created!");
                create.dispose();
                GUI gui = new GUI();
            }//if(pass.equals(conPass))
            else if(user.length()==0&&pass.length()==0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fill in the empty field!");
            }//check if both fields are blank
            else if (user.length()==0 &&pass.equals(pass)){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fill in the empty field!");
            }//check if user field is blank 
            else if(user.equals(user)&&pass!=conPass){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password do not match!");
            }//check if password and confirm pass matches
    }
```

I dont really know how to say  the problem but look in the `if` and `else if` statements, if the user meet one the those conditions, the program should print the `JOptionPane` thing. Except for the second else if.

You might be wondering why I put these codes at my `else if`

```
else if(user.equals(user)&&pass.equals(conPass)&&pass.length()!=0){
                String sqlLogin = "insert into tblLogin (username,pssword) values ('"+user+"','"+pass+"')";;
                getQuery(sqlLogin); 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account Successfully Created!");
                create.dispose();
```

The reason for this is that, my program is having some logic error when I try to put it in `if` statement. Please help me with my code thanks :) Feel free to write a new code for me :DD

Comment: what may cause an Exception if you put it in try clause.

Comment: what is this user.equals(user) check your order of if else

Comment: @mastah It gives an error if I didn't enclose it in a try catch

Comment: @Exbury `user.equals(user)` checks if the user has input something :P. I know its kinda stupid I can't think of anything better..yet

Comment: @Juju what may be the Exception source there?? i cant see anything that may throw one.
Edit: ahh, you create gui over there, make validation as an outside method which returns true is everything was done good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i might try something like this:

```
public static boolean isSet(String s){
     if(s==null || "".equals(s)) return false;
     return true;
}
//.... your validation here
if(isSet(user) && isSet(pass) && isSet(conPass) && pass.equals(conPass)){
    //create account
}else{
  //smth wrong eg. if(!pass.equals(conPass) { //wrongpass }
}
```

Comment: Can you further explain this to me :) I can't understand some codes on my own sorry :P.

Comment: this isnt much different than yours, just packs some operations in other methods, to not to see so messy code.

i would put whole data validation into new boolean method

Comment: Thanks for the effort! Would definitely try that :)

Comment: @Juju dont be affraid of making new methods :P they help making more clear code, so in future it will be easier to debug or prevent from errors :)
If answer helped please feel free to accept it, i would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Sorry , I forgot to click the checked XD And thank you for the advice :) I'll treasure that:))